# Make UIView fill UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a paging scrollview with two views, and the first one is to fill the `UIScrollview` and the second to stay in the middle. I don't know what's going wrong, but it wouldn't fill on iPhone6 but, it fits fine on iPhone5. Below is my code:

View Hierarchy

```
 UIView
        --StackView (Properties -- Axis(Vertical) Alignment(Fill) Distribution(Fill) Spacing(0))
            --UIView (Fixed height. 60)
            --UIView (Main Views Holder)
                --ScrollView(Content Size: Screen Width * 2, Height: Height left between it margin to the MainView and BottomView) and I notice, that the scrollview keeps remaining size 433 on both iPhone5 and 6. And when I check my storyboard, that's the exact same height there
                --UIView(Height: 102, Width: Screen Width)BottomView
```

---

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var rectanglePhot: UIView!
var squarePhoto: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    iniiCameraView()
}

func iniiCameraView() {
    rectanglePhot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)) <-- This is the problematic one
    //rectanglePhot = UIView()
    let specifyY = self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.width
    squarePhoto = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: specifyY, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.width))
    scrollView.addSubview(rectanglePhot)
    scrollView.addSubview(squarePhoto)

    rectanglePhot.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    squarePhoto.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    print("Rect Height ", rectanglePhot.frame.size.height)
    print("Scroll Height ", scrollView.frame.size.height)
    print("Specify Y ", specifyY)
}
```

And the image [Image Added to Scrollview a index[0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJMkK.jpg)

Comment: may be your view doesn't get right frame. set self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]

Comment: If it doesn't, `self.view.frame.size.width` should be floating out and `(self.view.frame.size.width*2)` for `UIScrollview contentSize` wouldn't be correct either

Comment: check if your scrollview is filling the entire screen by giving a border color to scrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code in viewdidappear. The autolayout will be applied after viewdidload

Comment: And, it worked. I knew I was supposed to use the loading hierarchy but was using the wrong one. Was using `viewWillAppear`

Comment: My scrollview is not responding to delegates though. Or is it because the delegate was set from storyboard?

Comment: just print the scrollview.delegate and make sure it is not nil.

Comment: Well, it just doesn't responding to this method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height))
```

With :

```
UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, height: self.scrollView.bounds.size.height))
```

With this the UIView will take the exact size of you scrollview

Comment: This `self.scrollView.frame.size.width` takes like one and a half of the contentSize too

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `autolayout`: add `subview`s in `viewDidLoad`, that is fine but you also need to adjust their `frame`s in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of `UIViewController` since your `scrollView` will have a different frame after `autolayout` passes.

if you are ok with using `autolayout`: don't rely on `scrollView` for sizing your `subview`s, relate size of your `subview`s to the size of `self.view`